# How do I recover master password in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I have set the master password in Mozilla Firefox. And now I have forgotten the password. How do I recover my master password?

Please Help.

Comment: This is off topic on Stack Overflow, and it's super trivial to Google. Searching `How do I recover master password in Mozilla Firefox?` solves all your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [Official Documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-your-master-password-if-you-forgot-it) to reset your master password in Mozilla Firefox. Please do note that you can not recover your password but you can always reset it. Read the official documentation for help.